# How to create new column in Pandas, based on another column by matching different string values?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create new column, based on text, included in a another columns string values.
i've got a large df with column 'start_url':

for exaple:

#### df['start_url'].head(4)

- 0 https://sitename.com/
- 1 https://sitename.com/about/news/
- 2 https://sitename.com/?click_id=8YeZ1Ti4adZixjK&city=City
- 3 https://sitename.com//product/

And i want something like this:

#### df['start_event'].head(4)

- 0 mainscreen
- 1 news
- 2 city_selection
- 3 product_page

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: @Tarique

Only this:

`df['start_event']=df['start_url']`

 `df['start_event']=df['start_event'].apply(lambda x: 'main' if x=='https://sitename.com/' else x)`

`df['start_event']=df['start_event'].apply(lambda x: 'city_selection' if x in 'https://sitename.com/?click_id=8YeZ1Ti4adZixjK&city=City' else x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.map()` function to do this:

```py
your_dic = {
    "https://sitename.com/": "mainscreen",
    "https://sitename.com/about/news/": "news",
    "https://sitename.com/?click_id=8YeZ1Ti4adZixjK&city=City": "city_selection",
    "https://sitename.com//product/": "product_page"
}
df['start_event'] = df['start_url'].map(your_dic)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting idea, but i have 190283 unique values of that column and dictionary for this column gonna be very large.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have your dictionary for the unique values of column 'start_url'? Then you want codes to find the dictionary itself and generate the columns 'start_event' just according to 'start_url' ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. The 'start_url' column has similar values, with different endings, for example:
* https://sitename.com//product/00001, https://sitename.com//product/00002, https://sitename.com//product/00003 and so on. So i need the way of detecting similar values with different endings and assign a new shared variable in the column 'start_event'